# ClickOnce: DeploymentDownloadException: The operation has timed out

Tags: deployment, timeout, clickonce

Symptom: ClickOnce installation starts and stops after around 600 kB (out of 2 MB).

Progress bar always stops at the same value (tried ten times).

Error log says that **The operation has timed out** (in inner exception) and fails with "**DeploymentDownloadException** (Unknown subtype)".

Error log details (irrelevant information trimmed):

`ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading http://fullpath/name.dll.deploy did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace: at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(Downloa
dQueueItem next)
            at
System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at
System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState
subState)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The operation has timed out.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer,
Int32 offset, Int32 size)
            at
System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(Downloa
dQueueItem next)`

---

This only happens for two customers. The install works OK for thousands of others. I have found numerous posts via google with no answer or generic "firewall is the issue" or "customer was using dialup".

Has anyone solved this? Is this a ClickOnce bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling firewall software on the machine did not help because a hardware firewall installed on the network was the cause (FortiGate 30B).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that it's a bug. However, it seems like it gets stuck at one file in the deployment path. Maybe it is a type of file that is blocked by a firewall.

I would just remove all files but one from the build and see if that gets downloaded ok, and then add the rest of the files one by one (or maybe type by type) and see at what file ClickOnce gets stuck downloading.

If that doesn't seem to do anything, I'd build a dummy app and deploy it with ClickOnce and see if it installs at all on the customer's box.